# gps orientation in android

Tags: android

I know that the function Location.getBearing() returns the bearing if any when in move

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location lastLocation)
  {
     int bearing=lastLocation.getBearing()
  }
```

,so now bearing might be , 170 degrees..but, I'd like to know if there is anything in android that will give me the direction of the orientation (ex for 170 degrees , the direction is : SSE  south, south east)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[getBearing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getBearing()) "returns the direction of travel in degrees East of true North".  Do a simple switch-case on the bearing to get directions.

Also note that 170° is closer to S (180°) than to SSE (157.5°).